# How to make a test that will wait 5 seconds before check element appearance (React testing lib)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my react component, I have an element that is appearing after 5 seconds.

I want to make a test that will check does element appear after 5 sec with `jest fake timers`, but can not make it work...

What I am doing wrong here?

One of the examples is not working:

```
it('check step 2 labels text, status "Submitted"', async () => {
    render(<ProgressIndicator appStatus="submitted" />);

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(5005);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(
        screen.getByText('Beep. Boop. Still doing our thing here.'),
      ).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('Verifying identity...')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

Second example:

```
it('check step 2 labels text, status "Submitted"', async () => {
    render(<ProgressIndicator appStatus="submitted" />);

    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(5005);
    });

    expect(
      screen.getByText('Beep. Boop. Still doing our thing here.'),
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('Verifying identity...')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule of thumb of using `await findBy` query and `await waitFor` is that you should use

> `await findBy` when you expect an element to appear but the change to the DOM might not happen immediately.

> and `await waitFor` when you have a unit test that mocks API calls and you need to wait for your mock promises to resolve.

The same is mentioned in the official documentation of the [dom-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor).

---

Now coming to your concern, you need to use `jest.useFakeTimer()` to enable fake timers that will help in mocking the setTimeout and other timer functions.

The same is mentioned here in [official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks).

useFakeTimer works with the [async methods](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor), however, if we want to work with sync methods like `getBy` queries then we have to use `jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000)` to move your test 5 (any specified time) seconds ahead of it. (example given below)

In the following example, I reproduce the concern that you have raised. I think this might help.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { act, render, screen, waitForElementToBeRemoved } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

const data = {
  name: 'subrato',
  age: 24,
};


function App() {
  const [myData, setState] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  function clickHandler() {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }, 5000);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {loading && <div aria-label='loading'>loading....</div>}
      <p>{myData?.name}</p>
      <p>{myData?.age}</p>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
describe('Test my app', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  it('display data', async () => {
    render(<App />);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Click me'));

    expect(screen.getByLabelText(/loading/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(await screen.findByText('subrato')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('24')).toBeInTheDocument();
   
  });

  it('display data second time', async () => {
    render(<App />);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Click me'));

    expect(screen.getByLabelText(/loading/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    act(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000));

    expect(screen.getByText('subrato')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('24')).toBeInTheDocument();
   
  });
});
```

Test Result

```
 PASS  src/TimerExample.spec.tsx (9.001 s)
  Test my app
    √ display data (487 ms)
    √ display data second time (35 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.997 s
Ran all test suites matching /TimerExample.spec.tsx/i.
```

Comment: I'd be glad to know if this solution solves your question.

Comment: For me it did not. yarn test command even exits with error.